# CSS menu, how to select parent

Tags: css, menu, parent-child

I have three items in a navigation menu

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu-topnav menu">
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl active-trail active">
            <a href="/le-reseau-pikard" class="topnav-3-pikard" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/12">Le Réseau Pikard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl">
            <a href="/accueil" class="topnav-3-pikard is-active" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/17">Pikard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl">
            <a href="https://isoprotek.fr" class="topnav-3-isoprotek">Isoprotek</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want the second `<a>` `is-active` CSS class disabled when the first parent `li` has `active` class. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to your question, and code example shared, the below should work by using the `+` next sibling selector.

```
li.active + li > a.is-active {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const firstLi = document.querySelector('.menu-topnav > li:first-of-type');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  let activeClass = firstLi.classList.contains('active') ? firstLi.classList.remove('active') : firstLi.classList.add('active');
  
});
```

```css
li.active + li > a.is-active {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="menu-topnav menu">
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl active-trail active">
            <a href="/le-reseau-pikard" class="topnav-3-pikard" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/12">Le Réseau Pikard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl">
            <a href="/accueil" class="topnav-3-pikard is-active" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/17">Pikard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--first-lvl">
            <a href="https://isoprotek.fr" class="topnav-3-isoprotek">Isoprotek</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<button>Toggle active class from first LI</button>
```